# call back after google plus share button

Tags: google-plus

i am implementing google plus in my application. i wanted to implement a callback function after the message was shared by a user. please let me know whether it is possible or not to implement callback after clicking on share button in google plus.

Thanks in advance
pratap

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two possible callbacks available by setting the share tag attributes or by setting parameters in a call to gapi.plus.render. The function specified by *onstartinteraction* is called when the share bubble pops up, and the function specified by *onendinteraction* is called when the bubble closes.

See https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharetag-parameters for further details.

Comment: thanks for the reply. onendinteraction working fine for g+1 button,will that work for share button in that page.if yes pleas give me an example how can i show popup after sharing the message

Answer (score 1):

Google+ Share buttons do not support callbacks. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=232) to add this functionality. Star it to show your interest but please do not add "+1" and "Me too!" comments.